# How to check if connection is open

Tags: c#, sockets, sleep, tcpclient

I have a problem when i'm trying to avoid using a `Thread.sleep(400)`
my code is like this:

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
clientSocket = Connect(IP, Port);
Thread.Sleep(400);

NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
Send(networkStream, "My Data To send");
networkStream.Flush();
```

and my send() method:

```
public static void Send(NetworkStream networkStream, string Data)
{
    int range = 1000;
    int datalength = 0;
    foreach (string data in Enumerable.Range(0, Data.Length / range).Select(i => Data.Substring(i * range, range)))
    {
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        networkStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        datalength = datalength + range;
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
    byte[] LastoutStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.Substring(datalength, Data.Length - datalength) + "$EOS$\r\n");
    networkStream.Write(LastoutStream, 0, LastoutStream.Length);
}
```

the Connect method:

```
 protected static System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Connect(string Ip, int Onport)
    {
        //start connection
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(Ip, Onport);
        }
        catch
        {
            clientSocket.Connect("LocalHost", Onport);
        }
        return clientSocket;
    }
```

is there a way to check if the stream is ready to be used?

Comment: Your stream should be ready for use immediately. How does your problem manifest itself without the Sleep?

Comment: by ready to be used, you mean not already used ? Check [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your Connect method?

Comment: Remove `Thread.Sleep(4000)` if you wish to *to avoid using* it =D

Comment: If i remove the sleep i dont get a response after i have send the second message and if i only sleep 300 it some times work and other times i get the same problem (this is only a problem if i send my messages right after each other)

Comment: why dont you check the TcpClient.Connected Property to see if you are connected and then proceed to send data?

Comment: i tried to make a `while (!clinetSocket.Connected);` but it is allways true

Comment: What service are you connecting to? Perhaps you send data before the service has indicated it is ready?

Comment: i asked the guy how made the program im connectiong to, and he found an bug in his code. Now it works without the sleep

Comment: @ReneNielsen always handle the exceptions expecting the other code to be defective!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your code is working I like to point out these regarding the stream

`GetStream()` returns exception only on 2 cases and these exceptions are ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

1. InvalidOperationException - The TcpClient is not connected to a remote host.
2. ObjectDisposedException - The TcpClient has been closed.

So your stream should be available if you meet this two conditions

Its always good to write exception logic in your code for the same reasons like the other party have bugs in their code.

In your own `connect()` method you should find out the exception and notify the called function that connect was unsuccessful or throw the exception back to caller function and have a try catch to handle it. So in successful case you will always get your stream.

```
try{
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
clientSocket = Connect(IP, Port);
//Thread.Sleep(400);

NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
Send(networkStream, "My Data To send");
networkStream.Flush();
}catch(Exception E)
{
 //Log
 //Its always best to catch the actual exception than general exception
 //Handle gracefully
}
```

Connect Method or you can leave out the exception to fall back to caller

```
 protected static System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Connect(string Ip, int Onport)
    {
        //start connection
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(Ip, Onport);
        }
        catch
        {
            //clientSocket.Connect("LocalHost", Onport);
            throw;
        }
        return clientSocket;
    }
```